# Why do we need texture filtering (bi-linear, trilinear, anisotropy...)

Tags: graphics, 3d, textures, texture-mapping

Maybe my understand about how texture mapping is implemented is wrong. I recently built a 3D engine purely in Java (I know I have a lot of time on my hand) and I finished the texture mapping part. The way I did it was as I draw the pixel to the screen, I look up the color for the texture at that location. I know that texture filtering helps reduce the blurriness on the texture at high distance viewed at a more oblique angle. But why does that problem even occur in the first place? It didn't in my implementation. Why would we lose resolution when we shrink an image?
Here's an image of my engine.
[image]

Comment: I think the actual problem filtering solves is not blurriness, but the oversharpened look that you get on the far side of your plane. *Bad* filtering makes it look blurry instead. See: http://oi62.tinypic.com/zmds7n.jpg

Comment: Also, think about why image editing programs perform filtering when they shrink images. You're losing resolution, because you have fewer pixels available to represent the same image. So you do some filtering to try to make those pixels represent more than one source pixel each.

Comment: Well when I shrink an image, I have way more pixels than how much I need to draw. All i have to do is pick out which pixel I want to draw. That won't result in blurry image. When I stretch an image, however, I don't have enough pixels to cover the bigger canvas and I'll have to start interpolating the middle pixels, that results in a blurry image.

Comment: When you have to pick which pixel to draw, you are leaving out information. It won't make a blurry image, but it will make a jagged one usually. Look at this: can you see the difference between shrinking the image with "nearest neighbour" (your algorithm) and Paint.Net's "Best" algorithm ? https://i.imgur.com/7csNSaA.png

Comment: That makes sense but most of the sources online says that no AF will result in textures being stretched and blurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two words: Nyquist Theorem.

Your texture is a signal and screen pixels are sampling positions (hence the term sampler for the unit that, well, samples the texture to screen pixels). The Nyquist Theorem says that to faithfully represent a signal with samples the signal must not contain frequencies above half the average sampling frequency. If that constraint is not met, aliasing will occour. So when you minify a texture you're essentially subsampling it, which will lead to aliasing if the sampling distance in the texture signal becomes larger (i.e. the sampling frequency lower) than twice the distance between the highest resolved texture features.

Hence in every discrete sampling system there is a so called "antialiasing filter" put in place before the sampler.

Comment: Quick question before I vote this as the answer. So anisotropy is an anti-aliasing algorithm?

Comment: @JackLe: No. Anisotropy is the noun (as in the dictionary) describing that things are not the same regardless of direction. In case of texture filtering anisotropy means that the filtering cutoff frequency changes between directions to reflect the sampling density in either direction. Also you normally don't apply filter "algorithms" but methods (subtle difference in meaning).

Comment: I did a good chunk of wikipedia reading. Apparently the pixels on screen stretches in differently vertical as it does horizontally in 3d space. MIPmapping uses isotropic scaling meaning that the scaled textures shrink the same amount in both x and y direction which is not suitable for the way the pixels stretch on the screen. Anisotropy uses RIP mapping which stretches the textures one direction at a time allowing it to find a "perfect" texture mapping size. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Two Words:  Moire Pattern

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

If your texture has a regular repeating pattern in it, then when the frequency at which it's sampled gets close to the frequency of the pattern in the texture, then these patterns of large light and dark areas will show up.

That's why checkerboards are used so often to show the benefits of bilinear filtering.

Try your engine with a checkerboard texture.

Note that this *is* a frequency aliasing effect, as mentioned in the "Nyquist theorem" answer, but this particular kind of aliasing effect is easy to understand without any complex math.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily understand that when you display less pixels than those present in the original image, you lose information and create unpleasing artifacts. There are too many details and you throw some of them rather arbitrarily.

Think of a sequence or red/green/blue pixels. If you sample every other three pixel, you will get a pure red, pure green or pure blue row, depending on where you start. And if the sampling ratio is close to three, you will observe a sequence of several red then green then blue pixels after each other. This is called aliasing. (Like in the olds days, when you were shrinking a sprite by straight decimation, the effect was disastrous.)

The cure is to let the destination pixel be a mixture of the source pixels it covers, and this is equivalent to the effect of an averaging filter. Actually, you throw the fine details more uniformly, by reducing their amplitude. The filter will be anisotropic when the scaling factors are different in X and Y.

Also note that interpolation is of no help, as it creates subpixel resolution when what you need is superpixel resolution. (In the previous example, you would get a slow blend between RGB runs.)